# Get all array objects with unique property id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a User modal with a `has_many` relationship to a Notification modal, which has a `notifier_id` property that equals some `User.id`

I'm trying to write some logic to get a list of the most recent Notifications for each User that has sent a Notification to some given User, but I'm confused about the best way to do that.

I tried this:

`@notifications = @user.notifications.uniq { |note| note.notifier_id }`

but it gives me all existing Notifications, with no filtering.

I found a SO post about a similar issue with a solution looking similar to this:

```
@notifications = @user.notifications.map { |note| note.notifier_id }
  .uniq
  .map{ |notifier_id| Notification.find(notifier_id) }
```

But this doesn't work for me because there are many Notifications with the same `notifier_id`

The only other option I can think of is to loop through all User.notifications, add each unique `notifier_id` to an array, then use that array to build another array of just the first notification from each unique notifier, but I feel like there should be a better way to do this. Is there?

UPDATE:

here is the generated SQL for: `@user.notifications.select("DISTINCT notifications.notifier_id")`

```
SELECT DISTINCT notifications.notifier_id FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "notifications"."created_at" DESC
```

UPDATE:

here is the solution I adapted:

```
inner = Notification.
  order(nil).
  select("DISTINCT notifications.notifier_id, notifications.*").
  where("notifications.user_id = ?", @user.id)
@notifications = Notification.from("(#{inner.to_sql}) notifications").
  order("notifications.created_at DESC")
```

here is its SQL:

```
Notification Load (3.3ms)  SELECT "notifications".* FROM (SELECT DISTINCT notifications.notifier_id, notifications.* FROM "notifications" WHERE (notifications.user_id = 313)  ORDER BY "notifications"."created_at" DESC) notifications  ORDER BY "notifications"."created_at" DESC, notifications.created_at DESC
```

The output is the same as @user.notifications

TEMPORARY SOLUTION:

This accomplishes what I want, but I'd like to use a SQL query instead

```
notifiers = []
@user.notifications.each do |note|
  if note.notifier_id
    found = false
    notifiers.each do |notifier_id|
      if notifier_id == note.notifier_id
      found = true
        break
      end
    end
    if !found
      notifiers << note.notifier_id
    end
  end
end

notifiers.each do |notifier_id|
  @notifications << @user.notifications.find{|x| x.notifier_id == notifier_id}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` to select all unique notifications based on `notifier_id`.

```
inner = Notification.
  order(nil).
  select("DISTINCT notifications.notifier_id, notifications.*").
  where("notifications.user_id = ?", current_user.id)
Notification.from("(#{inner.to_sql}) notifications").
  order("notifications.created_at DESC")
```

Comment: Ok I tried that but still received all notification objects

Comment: @Cbas Could you post the SQL being generated when you run the query?

Comment: @Cbas You're running the wrong code. It should be `user.notifications.uniq(:notifier_id)`, not `user.notifications.uniq { :notifier_id }`

Comment: Ok I changed it but now I get a 500 error `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):`

Comment: @Cbas I misread the API. I've updated my answer. Try it out and see if it works.

Comment: getting another 500 error `ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

Comment: @Cbas Are you ordering the result as well? I can't see anything about that in your post.

Comment: I updated the SQL - looks like there is a ordering operation, but I'm not sure where its coming from since this is the only line of code in the function.

Comment: @Cbas You can run `order(nil)` on it, that will remove the ordering. I'll post an updated query in a moment, but try that one in the mean time.

Comment: @Cbas I've updated my answer. I'll add an explanation later on.

Comment: The return of `Notification.from` is still all of the users notifications. It's the same as `@user.notifications`

Comment: @Cbas No, not in the code I posted. It will only return unique notifications based on `notifications.notifier_at`.

Comment: I ran it and it output the same result

Comment: @Cbas Always post your query when it doesn't do what you're asking. Otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97572/discussion-between-oleander-and-cbas).

Comment: I added some details to our chat, the latest code resulted in an SQL failure